# Avoiding dummy columns when using \cmidrule

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I have to typeset a table that comprises three "main columns" A, B and C, where B and C contain two and three "sub-columns", respectively.

[image: Output of the MWE]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0]cS[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]cS[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=1.0]}
\toprule
{A} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
&& {D} & {E} && {F} & {G} & {H} \\
\midrule
1 &&  8 &  9 && 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 &&  9 & 10 && 1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 && 10 & 11 && 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to achieve a similar result than using dummy columns between the "main columns" A, B and C? In my point of view, the spacing between the "main columns" could be a little less.

Comment: `\cmidrule(lr){1-2}`

Comment: You can modify the amount of trimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to applying left- and right-trimming to the `\cmidrule` lines, you may also want to get rid of the "overhangs" at the left- and right-hand edges of the `tabular` environment. For sure, that's also the general recommendation of the author of the `booktabs` package if the objective is to create a crisp-looking tableau.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=1.0] 
               *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]} 
               *{3}{S[table-format=1.0]} @{}}
\toprule
{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{C} \\
% two-sided trimming of interior cmidrules, 
% one-sided trimming of exterior cmidrules
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6} 
& {D} & {E} & {F} & {G} & {H} \\
\midrule
1 &  8 &  9 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 &  9 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 10 & 11 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/) I can easily answer the question myself.

I obtain the result

[image: Output of the MWE]

by using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{.4em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=1.0]}
\toprule
{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
& {D} & {E} & {F} & {G} & {H} \\
\midrule
1 &  8 &  9 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 &  9 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 10 & 11 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```